# Stripe + Parse Live/Production errors IOS

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

My app uses Stripe and Parse to accept donations as well as sign up customers for subscriptions. 
Everything worked well in test mode with the Test Secret code and Test Publishing Code but now that I switched it to the Live Keys, Im getting Card_errors and Invalid_Request_Errors.

Purchase= Donation Code;

Subscribe = Subscription Code;

Parse Cloud Code:

```
    var Stripe = require('stripe');
Stripe.initialize('sk_live_********....');

Parse.Cloud.define("purchase", function(request, response) {
                   var AD = request.params.amountDue;
                   var fullName = request.params.fullname;

                   Stripe.Charges.create({

                                                            description: fullName,
                                                            amount: AD * 100,
                                                            currency: "usd",
                                                            card: request.params.token
                                                            },{
                                                            success: function(httpResponse)
                                                            {
                                                            response.success("Purchase made!");
                                                            },

                                                            error: function(httpResponse)
                                                            {
                                                            response.error(httpResponse);
                                                            }
                                                            });
                                      });

    Parse.Cloud.define("subscribe", function(request, response) {
                       var fullName = request.params.fullname;

                       Stripe.Customers.create({
                                             description: fullName,
                                             email: request.params.email,
                                             plan: request.params.plan,
                                             card: re

    quest.params.token
                                             },{
                                             success: function(httpResponse)
                                             {
                                             response.success("Subscription made!");
                                             },

                                             error: function(httpResponse)
                                             {
                                             response.error(httpResponse);
                                             }
                                             });
                       });
```

Donation Code:

```
- (void)createBackendChargeWithToken:(STPToken *)token completion:(STPTokenSubmissionHandler)completion {



        NSNumber *amountDue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:priced.doubleValue];

        NSDictionary *productInfo = @{
                                      @"fullname": fullname,
                                      @"amountDue": amountDue,
                                      @"token": token.tokenId,
                                      };
        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"purchase"
                           withParameters:productInfo
                                    block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                        if (error) {
                                            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Error")
                                                                        message:[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"]
                                                                       delegate:nil
                                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK")
                                                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

                                        } else {

                                        }
                                    }];






        completion(STPBackendChargeResultSuccess, nil);
        return;


}
```

Subscription Code:

```
- (void)createBackendChargeWithToken:(STPToken *)token completion:(STPTokenSubmissionHandler)completion {


    NSDictionary *productInfo = @{
                                  @"fullname ":self.name.text,
                                  @"token": token.tokenId,
                                  @"email": self.email.text,
                                  @"plan": @"000000",
                                  };
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"subscribe"
                       withParameters:productInfo
                                block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                    if (error) {
                                        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Error")
                                                                    message:[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"]
                                                                   delegate:nil
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK")
                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

                                    } else {

                                    }
                                }];






    completion(STPBackendChargeResultSuccess, nil);
    return;


}
```

Why am I getting these errors if it worked in test mode?
Note: Although I'm testing in Live Mode, the app is still not not the app store or test flight, its simply being side loaded through Xcode. Could this be the problem?

EDIT:

In test mode, Im getting Card_Error when I use a real card, but it goes through when using 4242424242424.....

Comment: In test mode a real card should never work, a real card should work in live mode (though you should not do extensive testing in live mode. What is the full error message you get?

Comment: Figured that out, realized the card was just getting declined. Created a new stripe account and everything worked fine. Not sure why the cards getting declined on the first account

Comment: You should probably contact your bank or Stripe to avoid raising any flags